# Flutter: In stateless widget I get "The instance member 'xy' can't be accessed in an initializer." when using length on array xy

Tags: flutter, dart, final, stateless

This is now the 2nd spot in my code where I face this issue (1st one still pending, because I thought it would be caused by something else)

In a child stateless class I create a final based on a parameter being passed to this class. This throws **The instance member 'parameters' can't be accessed in an initializer.**

```dart
class createParameterButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Parameter> parameters;
  final String unnknown;
  createParameterButtons({this.parameters, this.unnknown});
  final noOfButtons = parameters.length;
  final loopEnd = (noOfButtons / 7).truncate() + (noOfButtons % 7 < 5 ? 1 : 2);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text("a"),
    ],
    ),
}  }
```

In guess I have figured out that I cannot use variables in a stateless widget (though I could have one in a for loop). But why doesn't a final based on a parameter work? Is this a general design or am I doing anything stupid?

I know, I can send the array length as another parameter as a workaround. But I would like to understand the problem.

Comment: especially as the problem continues with "loopEnd=" after passing the number of elements to the class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to the order of things happening when you call the constructor. Both parameters and noOfButtons are fields and one is not necessarily assigned before the other. If you want to use fields in other final fields, you have to do it in the initializer list. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list.

So, this should work:

```
class createParameterButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Parameter> parameters;
  final String unnknown;
  createParameterButtons({this.parameters, this.unnknown}) : noOfButtons = parameters.length, loopEnd = loopEnd = (noOfButtons / 7).truncate() + (noOfButtons % 7 < 5 ? 1 : 2);
  final noOfButtons;
  final loopEnd;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text("a"),
    ],
    ),
}  }
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand the notation of classname(...) : which I have already noticed before. I am accepting this answer because it is timely the 1st explaining the reason and providing the solution with the initializer list (which I find a bit cleaner that a declaration in the build method). THANKS TO ALL OF YOU!

Answer (score 3):

You could just make your variables local variables to your build method.

If for some reason they *need* to be class members, you need to initialize them in the constructor, that is called an [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list):

```
class createParameterButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Parameter> parameters;
  final String unknown;
  final int noOfButtons;
  final int loopEnd;

  createParameterButtons({this.parameters, this.unknown})
  : noOfButtons = parameters.length,
    loopEnd = (parameters.length / 7).truncate() + (parameters.length % 7 < 5 ? 1 : 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

> final loopEnd = ...

create a class property. It is executed before the object is initialized, so you can't access `this` (or `this.noOfButtons` in this case) since it might not be initialized yet. You can initialize the `loopEnd` inside the `build` method instead, then the object is fully created.

Btw, according to [convention](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) you should name the class in UpperCamelCase, so `class CreateParameterButtons`  instead of `class createParameterButtons`

Comment: "you should name the class in UpperCamelCase," Thanks. One typo propagated by copy paste :-) Others are UpperC...